# can't set an image in ListView in winform (c#)

Tags: c#

I am working on WinMobile and running my code on the emulator. 
My code for setting the image is:

```
ImageList il = new ImageList();
if (File.Exists(@"online1.BMP"))
    il.Images.Add((Image)new Bitmap(@"c:\online1.BMP"));
```

For some reason, the condition is always FALSE, although the file exists in the folder.
Does the "File.Exists" function refers to the phone's library? or the computer's (as I assume)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use full path as param to File.Exists()